# How do you align three columns with date range so they are all next to each other using BOOTSTRAP/Angular 13

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, angular13

I'm using this Bootstrap date range where the [TWO DIVS](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#date-range) are next to each other

What I need to do is show THREE DATE RANGES in three divs on one ROW.

This is what I want to do

```
<div class="input-group input-daterange">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-05">
    <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-19">
</div>
```

[image: Example of what I want]

This is what actually is happening

[image: What's actually happening]

Here's my current code:

```css
.labeldate1 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.labeldate2 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

.labeldate3 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: left;
}

.textinputdateadjust1 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  max-width: 25rem;
}

.textinputdateadjust2 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  max-width: 25rem;
}

.textinputdateadjust3 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  max-width: 25rem;
}

.input-daterange {
  width: 20%;
}

.daterangeLabel {
  margin-left: 45px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group datesactiveservice">
      <h3>{{enumProps.ACTIVESVCDATES}}</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="input-group input-daterange">
            <label for="datesactivesvc1a" class="labeldate1">Active Dates 1</label>
            <input id="datesactivesvc1a" name="datesactivesvc1a" formControlName="datesactivesvc1a" class="textinputdateadjust1 form-control" placeholder="Enter Start Date">
            <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
            <input id="datesactivesvc1b" name="datesactivesvc1b" formControlName="datesactivesvc1b" class="textinputdateadjust1 form-control" placeholder="Enter End Date">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="input-group input-daterangea">
            <label for="datesactivesvc2a" class="labeldate2">Active Dates 2</label>
            <input id="datesactivesvc2a" name="datesactivesvc2a" formControlName="datesactivesvc2a" class="textinputdateadjust2 form-control" placeholder="Enter Start Date">
            <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
            <input id="datesactivesvc2b" name="datesactivesvc2b" formControlName="datesactivesvc2b" class="textinputdateadjust2 form-control" placeholder="Enter End Date">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="input-group input-daterangea">
            <label for="datesactivesvc3a" class="labeldate3">Active Dates 3</label>
            <input id="datesactivesvc3a" name="datesactivesvc3a" formControlName="datesactivesvc3a" class="textinputdateadjust3 form-control" placeholder="Enter Start Date">
            <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
            <input id="datesactivesvc3b" name="datesactivesvc3b" formControlName="datesactivesvc3b" class="textinputdateadjust3 form-control" placeholder="Enter End Date">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You've set your containers to take 4/12 width only at medium breakpoint and up. Is that the problem?

Comment: FYI, you have horizontal scrolling because you lack a container element. Almost any outer row should be the child of a Bootstrap container.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix the problem with pure CSS.

```
.dateRowAdjust1 {
  max-width: 33.3%;
  margin-top: -32px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: -35px;
  margin-bottom: -35px;
}
.dateRowAdjust2 {
  max-width: 33.3%;
  margin-top: -36px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: -35px;
  margin-bottom: -35px;
}
.dateRowAdjust3 {
  max-width: 33.3%;
  margin-top: -52px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: -35px;
  margin-bottom: -35px;
}
.labels {
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 460px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.labeldate1 {
  margin-left: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.labeldate2 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 94px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.labeldate3 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.textinputadjust {
  margin-left: 50px;
  max-width: 77rem;
}
.textinputdateadjust1a {
  margin-left: 50px;
  max-width: 17rem;
}
.textinputdateadjust1b {
  margin-left: 340px;
  max-width: 17rem;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -45px;
}
.textinputdateadjust2a {
  margin-left: 50px;
  max-width: 17rem;
}
.textinputdateadjust2b {
  margin-left: 340px;
  max-width: 17rem;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -45px;
}
.textinputdateadjust3a {
  margin-left: 50px;
  max-width: 17rem;
}
.textinputdateadjust3b {
  margin-left: 340px;
  max-width: 17rem;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -45px;
}
```

And added BsDatePicker to the mix

```
                       <div class="row">
                          <div class="form-group datesactiveservice">
                            <h3>{{enumProps.ACTIVESVCDATES}}</h3>
                            <div class="col-md-4 dateRowAdjust1">
                              <div class="input-group input-daterange">
                                <label for="datesactivesvc1a" class="labeldate1">Active Dates 1</label>
                                <input id="datesactivesvc1a" name="datesactivesvc1a" formControlName="datesactivesvc1a"
                                  class="textinputdateadjust1a form-control" placeholder="Enter Start Date"
                                  bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="{ isAnimated: true }">
                                <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
                                <input id="datesactivesvc1b" name="datesactivesvc1b" formControlName="datesactivesvc1b"
                                  class="textinputdateadjust1b form-control" placeholder="Enter End Date">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 dateRowAdjust2">
                              <div class="input-group input-daterange">
                                <label for="datesactivesvc2a" class="labeldate2">Active Dates 2</label>
                                <input id="datesactivesvc2a" name="datesactivesvc2a" formControlName="datesactivesvc2a"
                                  class="textinputdateadjust2a form-control" placeholder="Enter Start Date">
                                <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
                                <input id="datesactivesvc2b" name="datesactivesvc2b" formControlName="datesactivesvc2b"
                                  class="textinputdateadjust2b form-control" placeholder="Enter End Date">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 dateRowAdjust3">
                              <div class="input-group input-daterange">
                                <label for="datesactivesvc3a" class="labeldate3">Active Dates 3</label>
                                <input id="datesactivesvc3a" name="datesactivesvc3a" formControlName="datesactivesvc3a"
                                  class="textinputdateadjust3a form-control" placeholder="Enter Start Date">
                                <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
                                <input id="datesactivesvc3b" name="datesactivesvc3b" formControlName="datesactivesvc3b"
                                  class="textinputdateadjust3b form-control" placeholder="Enter End Date">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

and it looks like this.
[image: Completed Side by Side Dates]